# Singularity of $\Gamma(g) - I$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a non-trivial irreducible unitary representation(also suppose of finite degree $d$) of a nontrivial group $G$. Consider the matrices $\Gamma(g) - I$, where $g\in G$ and $I$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix. It seems highly unlikely that all such matrices could be simultaneously singular. In other words, how can one show that there exists at least one $g$ such that $\Gamma(g)-I$ is invertible?

Comment: Well, It's false for the trivial group with one element.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy G is non-trivial as mentioned in the problem statement

Comment: oops. My mistake.

Comment: How is this supposed to be a physics question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind If $\{\psi_i\}_{i=1}^{d}$ are degenerate levels giving a degree-$d$ representation of the symmetry group $G$ of a system described by $H\psi=E\psi$ then prove or disprove  $\int \psi_i=0$, the integration being over the configuration space. The integral should be  invariant under any spatial transformation in $G$. At the same time $\psi_i$ is transformed to $\sum_{k=1}^{d}[\Gamma(g)]_{ki}\psi_k$. Then one has $\int \psi_i=[\Gamma(g)]_{ki}\int\psi_k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true for the $3$-dimensional irreducible representation of $A_4$. Elements of order $2$ are mapped to a matrix with eigenvalues $1,-1,-1$, and elements of order $3$ are mapped to one with eigenvalues $1,\omega,\omega^2$, with $\omega^3=1$.